# Detecting similar strings in Ruby.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, include

In my db, there are entries eg. `Тормозной диск`, `Диски тормозные LPR` etc. in `art_groups_arr` array. I would like to find all the entries similar to `Тормозной диск`, such as `Диски тормозные LPR`

This code:

```
art_groups_arr.each do |artgrarr|
  if n2.art_group.include?(artgrarr)
    non_original << n2
  end
end
```

does not find them, obviously. How can I find those similar strings?

Comment: Why would that be true ?

Comment: @oldergod  becouse it has many same letters :D  but on sence it is the same... but computer didn't have IO, but how to introduce it in this example...

Comment: I guess you will have to go to compare whether both Диски Тормозные or  Тормозные Диски is present in the array.

Comment: @AlokSwain no.... one is in plural and has other order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perhaps use regex, for example:

```
art_groups_arr.each do |art_gr_arr|
  if n2.art_group.any? { |element|
    /ормозн/ =~ element and /диск/ =~ element
  } then non_original << n2 end
end
```

Alternatively, [you can try out fuzz_ball gem](https://github.com/vincentchu/fuzz_ball) that claims to implement Smith-Waterman algorithm.

```
require 'fuzz_ball'
THRESHOLD_SCORE = 0.75
MATCHER = FuzzBall::Searcher.new [ 'Тормозной диск LPR' ]

def complies?( str )
  matchdata = MATCHER.search str
  return false if matchdata.nil? or matchdata.empty?
  score = matchdata[0][:score]
  puts "score is #{score}"
  score > THRESHOLD_SCORE
end

art_groups_arr.each do |art_gr_arr|
  if n2.art_group.any? { |element| complies? element } then
    non_original << n2
  end
end
```

For `'Диски тормозные LPR'` you get score `0.861`, you have to tune the threshold.

Comment: In such case, you will need a string classification algorithm. You will need to make a decision and choose one first. You could for example compute the distance of your string from 'Тормозный Диск'. Such algorithms are used for example for sequence comparison in biolgy.

Comment: [Here you go, string metrics, choose one...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) I would suggest something like Smith-Waterman algorithm.

Comment: I tried fuzz_ball and it is always crashing with Ruby 1.9.x.  See https://github.com/vincentchu/fuzz_ball/issues/1

Comment: @chrish: I myself had crash cases with `fuzz_ball`. If you find better Smith-Waterman gem, let me know.